# Prevent Repeated Execution of ASP.NET Button Click Event After ConfirmBox Prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on an ASP.NET application where I have a button in my ASPX page. I am trying to trigger its click event through JavaScript within a setTimeout function after a confirmBox appears, prompting the user with 'yes' or 'no'.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="return showConfirmBox();" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isButtonClicked = false;
    function showConfirmBox() {
        if (!isButtonClicked) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')) {
                    isButtonClicked = true; // Set the flag to true to prevent further clicks
                    document.getElementById('<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click();
                } else {
                    // Handle the case when the user clicks 'no'
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        // Prevent the button click event from executing immediately
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Certainly! Here's the updated Stack Overflow question that includes all the details:

Title: Prevent Repeated Execution of ASP.NET Button Click Event After ConfirmBox Prompt in JavaScript

Description:

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on an ASP.NET application where I have a button in my ASPX page. I am trying to trigger its click event through JavaScript within a setTimeout function after a confirmBox appears, prompting the user with 'yes' or 'no'.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="return showConfirmBox();" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isButtonClicked = false;
    function showConfirmBox() {
        if (!isButtonClicked) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')) {
                    isButtonClicked = true; // Set the flag to true to prevent further clicks
                    document.getElementById('<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click();
                } else {
                    // Handle the case when the user clicks 'no'
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        // Prevent the button click event from executing immediately
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

In this setup, the `showConfirmBox()` function is triggered when the button is clicked. However, even after setting the flag isButtonClicked to true within the showConfirmBox function, the button click event continues to execute repeatedly. I want to prevent the button click event from being triggered again after it has been processed on the server. How can I achieve this?

I have already tried checking the isButtonClicked flag and returning false in the OnClientClick attribute, but the issue persists.

Any advice or suggestions on how to prevent the repeated execution of the button click event after the confirmBox prompt would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you looking to have a timeout delay part of this solution (user must hit buttion within 10 seconds, and the dialog closes??? Or is the time out garbage a 100% side show and has ZERO to do with the simple question of a dialog prompt, user hits Ok, or cancel, and if they hit ok, then we hide  or prevent user from hittin the button untll such time the server side code is done?  In fact, if you looking to have a dialog with a timeout, then we can't really use the confirm dialog, since it blocks running code. So, So, if you JUST looking to have a dialog pop confirm, then state so.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it just not clear why some timeout or timer issue is being introduced to this question.

The goal here is to pop a confirm dialog, and if user hits "ok" then we allow the server-side button event code to run (and ALSO want to prevent additional clicks until such time the server-side code is done).

And ALL of the above is rather easy. However, introduction of timer events suggests that you are looking to perhaps have the dialog close, or automatic dismiss after a given amount of time.

Since it is not clear what (or why) the concept of a timer is being introduced here, then we have to assume that "maybe" the user does, or does not want the dialog to automatic dismiss after a given amount of time.

However, regardless of above, the SIMPLE solution to preventing the button to be clicked again (at least until server-side code is done) is to with client-side code hide the button.

The beauty of this approach is that when the server-side code is complete, then no client-side code will be required to re-show the button (the page refresh will automatic do this for us).

So, the code could work this way:

markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me"
            OnClientClick="return showConfirmBox(this);"
            OnClick="myButton_Click"
            CssClass="btn" />

        <script>

            function showConfirmBox(btn) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')) {

                    $(btn).hide()   // hide the button, prevent future clicks
                    return true
                }
                // Prevent the button click event from executing immediately
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

And code behind for this test is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Protected Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' fake 2 second delay
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)


End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, the simple approach here is to hide the button, and thus the user can't click the button again, or repeated times. Of course, after the server-side code has run, then the button will reappear. It was never clear in your post that once the server-side code has completed, then is the button to redisplay or not. The above example assumes you wish to redisplay the button after server-side code is completed. So, the user can't click the button again "while" the server side code is running, and thus you not have multiple clicks occur while the server code is running. However, after the code has completed, the user can then click the button again.

Also, do follow up and ask if a dialog is to automatic dismiss after a given amount of time. Since you are using jQuery, then I would suggest in such a case to introduce a jQuery.UI dialog.